# How can i get children props value outside react map

Tags: reactjs, next.js

i want to add a class at Panel if any of it child have 'acitve' class. how can add 'parent-active' class if child element get 'active' class.
thank for your help!

```
const MyComponent = ({
  router,
  className,
  items
}) => {

  return (
    <Collapse accordion={true}>
      {items.map(dropdown => {
        return (
          <Panel
            header={dropdown.title}
            headerClass="dropdown-title"
            className={router.pathname === item.href ? 'parent-active' : ''}
            key={dropdown.id}
          >
            {dropdown.dropdownItems.length}
            {dropdown.dropdownItems.map(item => (
              <Link href={item.href} key={item.id}>
                <a
                  className={
                    router.pathname === item.href ? 'active' : ''
                  }
                >
                  {item.label}
                </a>
              </Link>
            ))}
          </Panel>
        );
      })}
    </Collapse>
  );
};

export default withRouter(MyComponent);
```

Comment: Christian has written a clear solution, but just to let you know, you've named the variable inside your first map method *item* instead of *dropdown*. The line className={router.pathname === item.href ? 'parent-active' : ''} should be  className={router.pathname === dropdown.href ? 'parent-active' : ''}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to determine if any of the children will have an `active` class:

```
const isAnyChildActive = dropdownItems.some((item) => router.pathname === item.href);
```

And the full code snippet:

```
const MyComponent = ({
  router,
  className,
  items
}) => {

  return (
    <Collapse accordion={true}>
      {items.map(dropdown => {
        const { dropdownItems } = dropdown;
        const isAnyChildActive = dropdownItems.some((item) => router.pathname === item.href);

        return (
          <Panel
            header={dropdown.title}
            headerClass="dropdown-title"
            className={isAnyChildActive ? 'parent-active' : ''}
            key={dropdown.id}
          >
            {dropdown.dropdownItems.length}
            {dropdown.dropdownItems.map(item => (
              <Link href={item.href} key={item.id}>
                <a
                  className={
                    router.pathname === item.href ? 'active' : ''
                  }
                >
                  {item.label}
                </a>
              </Link>
            ))}
          </Panel>
        );
      })}
    </Collapse>
  );
};

export default withRouter(MyComponent);
```